# How to draw circle with polygons in it?

Tags: diagrams

So usually if I have some problem with LaTeX, I google for some codes, then it works (also I understand the problem and the solution more). But now I can't find codes that I understand and work for me, and I have not enough time too. I need a picture like this: [image]

aOae = bObe = cOce = 60°. f1 is the bisector of aeb, same for (be,c,f2) and (ce,a,f3). I think thats all which is important.

Comment: You still need to put some effort into it. Show what you have. If you do not have anything - not even a circle or at line, then you need to study e.g. TikZ. If you do not have much time, then you are out of luck. As the question is now it is due to be closed as all you are doing is asking for someone to do your work.

Comment: And f1,f2,f3 form an equilateral triangle? If not, then the problem is not sufficiently defined. You have to sort out the math first.

Comment: Do you know the name of this nice construction,
or any reference where it is mentioned?

Comment: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Polya/07468342.di020785.02p0455x.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Here is a short code with `pstricks`, and more specifically with `pst-eucl`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
% \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} for use with pdflatex

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=3, PointSymbol=none}\small
\begin{pspicture}(-1.25,-1.25)(1.25,1.25)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={0,60,120,150,210,270,330}, PointName={,a, a\varepsilon, b, b\varepsilon, c, cε}, PointNameSep=6pt] (0,0){O}(1;60){a}(1;120){ae}(1;150){b}(1;210){be}(1;270){c}(1;330){ce}
    \pscircle(O){1}
    \foreach \angleA/\angleB in {60/120,150/210,270/330}{\pswedge[fillstyle=hlines, hatchwidth=0.4pt](O){1}{\angleA}{\angleB}}
    \psset{PointSymbol=x, fillstyle=none}
    \foreach \Beg/\End[count =\I] in {ae/b, be/c, ce/a/3}{\psline[linestyle=dashed, linewidth=0.5pt](\Beg)(\End)
            \pstMiddleAB[PointNameSep=1.5em]{\Beg}{\End}{f_\I}}
    \pspolygon(f₁)(f₂)(f₃)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity: I didn't know that. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, with `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, shapes.misc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[thick] circle (2cm);
\foreach \i/\j in {a/60,b/150,c/270}
    \draw[thick, pattern=north west lines] (O) -- 
          (\j:2cm) 
          coordinate[label={[circle, inner sep=1pt, anchor=180+\j]\j:$\i$}] (\i)
          arc(\j:\j+60:2cm) 
          coordinate[label={[circle, inner sep=1pt, anchor=240+\j]\j:$\i\epsilon$}] 
          (\i-e)--cycle;
\foreach \i/\j/\k [count=\f] in {a-e/b/135, b-e/c/240, c-e/a/15}
    \draw[dashed] (\i) -- 
    node[cross out, draw, label={[circle, inner sep=3mm, anchor=\k]\k:{$f_\f$}}] (f\f) {} 
    (\j);
\draw[thick] (f1.center) -- (f2.center) --(f3.center) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

And `Asymptote` version:

```
// sectors.asy
//
// run
//   asy sectors.asy
// to get sectors.pdf

settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph; import geometry;
import patterns; add("hatchback",hatch(2mm,plain.NW));
size(6cm); import fontsize; defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amsfonts}\usepackage{amssymb}");
pen linePen=darkblue+0.9bp, line2Pen=orange+0.9bp, grayPen=gray(0.3)+0.8bp, dashPen=grayPen+linetype(new real[]{5,5})+linecap(0);

pair O,A,B,C,Ae,Be,Ce;
O=(0,0);  draw(Circle(O,1),line2Pen);
A=rotate(42)*(1,0); Ae=rotate(60)*A; B=rotate(23)*Ae; Be=rotate(60)*B; C=rotate(93)*Be; Ce=rotate(60)*C;  
pair[] F={ (Ae+B)/2, (Be+C)/2, (Ce+A)/2, };
guide[] gsector={ O--Arc(O,A,Ae)--cycle, O--Arc(O,B,Be)--cycle, O--Arc(O,C,Ce)--cycle, };
for(var sector: gsector) filldraw(sector,pattern("hatchback"));
draw(Ae--B^^Be--C^^Ce--A,dashPen);
filldraw(F[0]--F[1]--F[2]--cycle,paleblue+opacity(0.3),red+colorless(linePen));
void mark60(pair A, pair B, pair C){ markangle(Label("$\tfrac\pi3$",Relative(0.5)),n=1,radius=-10,A,B,C,p=linePen+0.6bp);}
pair[][] angles={{Ae,O,A}, {Be,O,B}, {Ce,O,C}, {F[0],F[1],F[2]}, {F[1],F[2],F[0]}, {F[2],F[0],F[1]},};
for(var x:angles) mark60(x[0],x[1],x[2]);
dot(O--A--Ae--B--Be--C--Ce--F[0]--F[1]--F[2],UnFill);
void markEndSect(string s, pair P, pair Pe){ label("$"+s+"$",P,unit(P-O)); label("$"+s+"_{\varepsilon}$",Pe,unit(Pe-O));}
markEndSect("A",A,Ae); markEndSect("B",B,Be); markEndSect("C",C,Ce);
for(int i=0;i<F.length;++i)label("$F_{"+string(i+1)+"}$",F[i],unit(F[i]-O));
```

[image]